# MaterialCardView rounded corner only from top

Tags: android, rounded-corners, bottomsheetdialogfragment

I simply want to make my bottomSheetDialog round from top right and top left only.

I want to have my bottomSheetDialog rounded from top corner but straight from below..

I. have tried multiple ways to solve

**layout.xml**

```
<com.google.android.material.card.MaterialCardView
        android:id="@+id/cardViewInfo"
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        style="@style/CustomCardViewCornerStyle"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:background="@color/red_no"
        android:clickable="true"
        android:focusable="true"
        app:cardElevation="5dp">

        <androidx.constraintlayout.widget.ConstraintLayout
            android:layout_width="match_parent"
            android:layout_height="match_parent"
            android:background="@color/white">

            <androidx.appcompat.widget.AppCompatImageView
                android:id="@+id/imageViewPhoto"
                android:layout_width="match_parent"
                android:minHeight="200dp"
                android:layout_height="160dp"
                android:scaleType="center"
                app:layout_constraintDimensionRatio="h,375:240"
                app:layout_constraintTop_toTopOf="parent" />

            <androidx.appcompat.widget.AppCompatImageView
                android:id="@+id/imageViewCross"
                android:layout_width="48dp"
                android:layout_height="48dp"
                android:padding="8dp"
                app:layout_constraintEnd_toEndOf="parent"
                app:layout_constraintTop_toTopOf="parent"
                app:srcCompat="@drawable/ic_close_btn" />

            <matas.matas.core.control.TextViewInterRegular
                android:id="@+id/textViewExpiryDate"
                android:layout_width="0dp"
                android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                android:layout_marginStart="24dp"
                android:layout_marginTop="24dp"
                android:layout_marginEnd="24dp"
                android:gravity="center_horizontal"
                android:textColor="@color/colorBlackLight"
                android:textSize="10sp"
                android:lineHeight="12sp"
                app:layout_constraintStart_toStartOf="parent"
                app:layout_constraintTop_toBottomOf="@+id/imageViewPhoto"
                tools:text="Udløber xx.xx.xxxx" />

            <matas.matas.core.control.TextViewDMSerifRegular
                android:id="@+id/textViewName"
                android:layout_width="0dp"
                android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                android:layout_marginStart="24dp"
                android:layout_marginEnd="24dp"
                android:layout_marginTop="6dp"
                android:gravity="start"
                android:textColor="@color/black"
                android:textSize="24sp"
                android:lineHeight="28.8sp"
                app:layout_constraintStart_toStartOf="parent"
                app:layout_constraintEnd_toEndOf="parent"
                app:layout_constraintTop_toBottomOf="@+id/textViewExpiryDate"
                tools:text="40% på Striberne" />

            <matas.matas.core.control.TextViewInterSemiBold
                android:id="@+id/textViewTeaserText"
                android:layout_width="0dp"
                android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                android:layout_marginStart="24dp"
                android:layout_marginTop="16dp"
                android:layout_marginEnd="24dp"
                android:gravity="left"
                android:textColor="@color/black"
                android:textSize="14sp"
                android:lineHeight="21sp"
                app:layout_constraintEnd_toEndOf="parent"
                app:layout_constraintStart_toStartOf="parent"
                app:layout_constraintTop_toBottomOf="@+id/textViewName"
                tools:text="Du i hele februar 40% på ALLE produkter fra Matas striber." />


            <matas.matas.core.control.TextViewInterRegular
                android:id="@+id/textViewDisclaimerPlus"
                android:layout_width="0dp"
                android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                android:layout_marginTop="16dp"
                android:layout_marginStart="24dp"
                android:layout_marginEnd="24dp"
                android:layout_marginBottom="16dp"
                android:gravity="start"
                android:textColor="@color/colorBlackLight"
                android:textSize="12sp"
                app:layout_constraintEnd_toEndOf="parent"
                app:layout_constraintStart_toStartOf="parent"
                app:layout_constraintTop_toBottomOf="@+id/textViewTeaserText"
                app:layout_constraintBottom_toBottomOf="parent"
                tools:text="Kontakt en materialist her i butikken og vis dit medlemskort, så får du rabatten på dit køb" />

            <matas.matas.core.control.TextViewInterRegular
                android:id="@+id/textViewDisclaimerNonPlus"
                android:layout_width="0dp"
                android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                android:layout_marginTop="16dp"
                android:layout_marginStart="24dp"
                android:layout_marginEnd="24dp"
                android:layout_marginBottom="16dp"
                android:gravity="start"
                android:textColor="@color/colorBlackLight"
                android:textSize="12sp"
                app:layout_constraintEnd_toEndOf="parent"
                app:layout_constraintStart_toStartOf="parent"
                app:layout_constraintTop_toBottomOf="@+id/textViewTeaserText"
                app:layout_constraintBottom_toBottomOf="parent"
                tools:text="Kontakt en materialist her i butikken og vis dit medlemskort, så får du rabatten på dit køb" />

        </androidx.constraintlayout.widget.ConstraintLayout>
    </com.google.android.material.card.MaterialCardView>
```

I have tried multiple ways to make my image rounded and full width like

```
Glide.with(binding.imageViewPhoto)
                            .load(url)
                            .transform(GranularRoundedCorners(120.0f,120.0f,0.0f,0.0f))
                            .into(binding.imageViewPhoto)
```

**Also tried**

```
override fun onCreate(savedInstanceState: Bundle?) {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState)
        setStyle(STYLE_NORMAL, matas.matas.core.R.style.TopRoundedBottomSheetDialog)
    }
```

I have implemented theme in onCreate and also tried giving shape to it.

[image]

Answer (score 0):

Material Components take a shapeAppearance argument which you can use to provide proper shape to the bottom sheet, try using that instead of style. example given below

```
    <style name="shape_appearance_bottom_sheet">
        <item name="cornerFamily">rounded</item>
        <item name="cornerSizeTopLeft">20dp</item>
        <item name="cornerSizeTopRight">20dp</item>
        <item name="cornerSizeBottomLeft">0dp</item>
        <item name="cornerSizeBottomRight">0dp</item>
    </style>
```

you can then provide this style as follows to your material card

```
    <com.google.android.material.card.MaterialCardView
        app:shapeAppearance="@style/shape_appearance_bottom_sheet"
        app:cardPreventCornerOverlap="false"
    ....
```

The line `app:cardPreventCornerOverlap="false` prevents bottom sheet to add padding between your image and bottom sheet. This will make the image fill the card.

If you want to keep padding to the image remove `cardPreventCornerOverlap` and follow below steps.

create a drawable with only top borders.

```
<shape xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android">
    <solid android:color="#ffffff"/>
    <corners
        android:topRightRadius="@dimen/bottom_card_top_radius"
        android:topLeftRadius="@dimen/bottom_card_top_radius"/>
</shape>
```

Now, set this drawable as background to the image

```
<ImageView
    android:id="@+id/imageView"
    android:background="@drawable/top_corners"
    enter code here
```

and once you do this you need to write below kotlin code.

```kotlin
imageView.outlineProvider = ViewOutlineProvider.BACKGROUND
imageView.clipToOutline = true
```

Comment: I have already tried it as well. It cardPreventCornerOverlap make my imageView full width but the rounded shape I have applied to BottomSheet will not be there . I mean roundness is compromise

Comment: If you just want the image to be have the padding and still want it to have only top rounded corners you can create a drawable with only top corners, setting it as background for image and then calling clip to outline function from your kotlin/java code, I have updated the answer for that as well

Comment: Please try the updated answer

Answer (score 0):

Set the background of your imageview with shape of rounder corners

```
<shape xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android">
    <solid android:color="#ffffff"/>
    <corners
        android:topRightRadius="18dp"
        android:topLeftRadius="18dp"/>
</shape>
```